The contour integral of 1/z along the lower semicircle of radius 3 centered at 2
If C is the part of the half circle of radius 3 centered at 2 in the lower half complex plane (C : positive orientation), I'd like to calculate
$ ∫ _C   1/z \ dz $.
Can anybody help me?
I tried to used the parameter representation $ z(t) = 2 + 3e^{it} $, but nothing helpful...
I am not aware of the complex log and residue theorem.
I only know up to chapter 2 based on the stein textbook, which is

Continuous functions, Holomorphic functions,  Power series


Goursat’s theorem, Cauchy’s theorem in a
disc,  Cauchy’s integral formulas


Morera’s theorem,  Sequences of holomorphic functions,  Schwarz reflection principle, Runge’s approximation theorem

Thank you all for your help.

Are you assuming that all of us have access to that textbook?

Sorry, @José Carlos Santos. I just listed the theorems related to the problem that I know of in a post.

@Medo Cauchy's Integral Formula does not apply as the contour $C$ is not closed. (If I understood the definition of $C$ correctly.)

@spinosarus123 is right. C is not a closed curve. Thank you for your interest in my post.

You have\begin{align}\oint_C\frac{\mathrm dz}z&=\int_\pi^{2\pi}\frac{z'(t)}{z(t)}\,\mathrm dt\\&=\int_\pi^{2\pi}\frac{3ie^{it}}{2+3e^{it}}\,\mathrm dt\\&=\int_\pi^{2\pi}\frac{3ie^{it}(2+3e^{-it})}{(2+3e^{it})(2+3e^{-it})}\,\mathrm dt\\&=\int_\pi^{2\pi}\frac{9i+6ie^{it}}{13+12\cos(t)}\,\mathrm dt\\&=i\left(9\int_\pi^{2\pi}\frac1{13+12\cos(t)}\,\mathrm dt+6\int_\pi^{2\pi}\frac{\cos(t)}{13+12\cos(t)}\,\mathrm dt+\right.\\&\phantom=\quad+\left.6i\int_\pi^{2\pi}\frac{\sin(t)}{13+12\cos(t)}\,\mathrm dt\right)\\&=i\left(\frac{9\pi}5-\frac{4\pi}5-i\log(5)\right)\\&=\log(5)+\pi i.\end{align}

Although my post was not a good one, I really appreciate your help!

I'm glad I could help.

This is a nice trick to avoid dealing with the complex logarithm. (+1)

Taking a branch cut along the negative half of the real axis for the logarithmic function,
\begin{align}\oint_C\frac{\mathrm dz}z&=\int_\pi^{2\pi}\frac{z'(t)}{z(t)}\mathrm dt \\=&\int_\pi^{2\pi}\frac{3ie^{it}}{2+3e^{it}}\,\mathrm dt\\=& \log(2+3e^{2i\pi})-\lim_{t\rightarrow \pi^{+}}\log(2+3e^{it})\\=&\log(5)+\pi i.\end{align}

It is important to mind the discontinuity of the lograithmic function along the branch cut. Notice that  $\lim_{t\rightarrow \pi^{+}}\log(2+3e^{it})=-\pi i $ while $\lim_{t\rightarrow \pi^{-}}\log(2+3e^{it})=\pi i$.

Although i'm not aware of the details of complex logarithm and branch cut, I'm able to understand this problem now better with your explanation. Thank you.
